# How can I get a specific attribute value for all the keys contained in a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Hashmap:
`Map<String, Paper> numberMapping = new HashMap<>();`

class Paper `String[] author; String[] scores;`

I want to retrieve all the author of each object contained in the hashmap.

I tried `System.out.print(numberMapping.values().getAuthor());` but it's not working, how can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are not seeing a user friendly output cause you are printing String[] objects, which does not have a friendly toString() method.

Either use use `Set<String>` instead of `String[]`, which has a better implementation, or else assuming Java 8+, a functional way could be:

```
Set<String> allAuthors = numberMapping.values()
        .stream()
        .map(paper -> paper.author)
        .flatMap(author -> Arrays.stream(author))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(allAuthors);
```

Also it's common practice to use plurals for variables that refers to Collections.

I'm assuming the overall order of the output doesn't matter to you since you are using a `Hashmap` to store the values, as pointed out in the comments

Comment: Collecting to a `List` is a bit odd given both that you're starting with an unordered collection and you are using `distinct`.

Comment: that's fair @TomHawtin-tackline. I might get away because I didn't specify the Map implementation but I'd rather update the answer to suit better this case.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in following ways:

```
List<String[]> authors = ...
for (Paper paper : numberMapping.values()) {
    authors.add(paper.getAuthor());
}
//print authors
```

Alternatively, you could use Stream api like below:

```
System.out.println(numberMapping.values().stream().
                       map(paper -> paper.getAuthor()).
                       collect(Collectors::asList));
```

Now remember, you have array of authors, hence it might not print correctly as arrays doesn't have inbuilt toString implemented, hence you may need to iterate over each elements and print the authors using `Arrays.toString(authors)`.

Comment: Note that ur `map` call could use a method reference like `Paper::getAuthor`

Comment: Note that there is the helper `Arrays.toString(array)` that prints an array, no need for a manual iteration.

Comment: thanks @Zabuza. I used both the flavors in my example. Agree with you though. toString would be for one element in the list, you have multiple values hence `Arrays.toString` wont help.

Comment: Collecting to a `List` is a bit odd given that you're starting with an unordered collection.